# In EF Core, how do I configure the foreign key for reference owned types using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In a `Company` entity I have included `Address` as a reference [owned type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) (so that the `Company` table includes the properties of the address as columns).  The reference owned `Address` includes `Country` by holding the foreign key `CountryCode` which is a property of the `Address` class.  As such I need to configure this property as the foreign key.

When I use the attribute `ForeignKey("Country")` the migration is successful and the table is created with the correct column as FK: `[Companies].[Address_CountryCode]`.  However I want to use the Fluent API for all my EF Core DbContext configurations.  And this fails as the migration finds a conflict in ownership of `Address`.

```c
class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

```c
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().OwnsOne<Address>(c => c.Address);
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasOne<Country>(c => c.Country).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryCode);
```

Setting up the foreign key through Fluent API in this matter, fails with the following message:
`The type 'Address' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists.`.  Again, with the `ForeignKey` attribute it works as expected.

How do I configure this reference owned type relationship in Fluent API correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to nest your owned entities.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().OwnsOne<Address>(c => c.Address, a => {
    a.HasOne<Country>(c => c.Country).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryCode);
});
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#nested-owned-types